# How can I set the IP address on a Tomcat hostname?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I am not so into **Tomcat** configuration and I have the following problem.

I am working on a Java EE application that have Tomcat 7 configured in this way:

[image]

Into the **Host name** field there is setted the IP of my laptop (not **localhost**, there is the IP address). It is ok, it works fine and it have to be setted in this way so that my application works correctly).

My doubt is: where this information is stored? I tryied to search it into the **server.xml** configuration file but there is not.

My problem is that now I have to set this information also on a remote Tomcat server running on a Linux server (because I have to deploy my application on a test environment). So how can I set the IP address on a Tomcat server?

Comment: In the folder of tomcat there is 'conf' in there you will find server.xml if you search for 'Host' you will finde 'defauHost' and 'Host' you can change both. Check better i foudn them here.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration for Tomcat virtual host is by default in `conf/server.xml` and defined by `<Host>` XML element, which is nested inside `<Engine>` element. Check the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html) for more details. So, there you should find something like this:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    ...
    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        ....
    </Host>
</Engine>
```

On your remote server, you should just change the `name` attribute of `<Host>` element, to match the server's hostname.